# Interchanging addition and multiplication

Tags: operators, arithmetic

Suppose I have an expression that employs addition and multiplication, but no subtraction or division:
$$
2 a + 5 b x^3 + c \;.
$$
I would like to change this to
$$
(2 + a)  (5 +b + x +x +x)  c \;,
$$
where within each term, the products have become sums, and
at the top level, the sums have become products.
Is there a clever way to access the representation of the expression and
perform the operator swapping?

---

Responding to the comments:

```
z = FullForm[2 a + x^5];
Print[z];
z = z /. {Times -> Plus, Plus -> Times, Power -> Times};
Print[z];
Print[Evaluate[z]];
```

prints:

```
Plus[Times[2,a],Power[x,5]]
Times[5,Plus[2,a],x]
Times[5,Plus[2,a],x]
```

whereas I was hoping for
$$
5 (2 + a) x
$$

Comment: Take a look at `FullForm[2 a + 5 b x^3 + c]` then lookup `ReplaceAll` documentation. Keep in mind: `FullForm[a - b]` so either you will go fully consistent or you have to introduce exceptions.

Comment: @Kuba: Thanks, just what I was seeking.

Comment: So what Kuba said would mean `2 a + 5 b x^3 + c /. {Times -> Plus, Plus -> Times, Power -> Times}`. But do take great care to only have positive integers, and no `-` or `/` showing up ... the representation of those is less uniform.

Comment: How does one force evaluation of a FullForm expression? When `z` is the FullForm `Times[2,x,Plus[2,x]]`, `Evaluate[z]` leaves it unaltered.

Comment: There isn't really such a thing as "a FullForm expression".  When you evaluate `FullForm[expr]`, it will show you the internal structure of `expr` (but this output should not / cannot be used for further computations). Can you clarify what you meant with your last comment, through a concrete example?

Comment: @Szabolcs: "but this output should not / cannot be used for further computations"---This is precisely what I would like to do. There must be a way...

Comment: Will you be subtracting anything, or will there be negative quantities? How about divisions?

Comment: @J.M.: no subtraction or division.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke I think you may have a fundamental misunderstanding about the structure of expressions, but due to the limitation of comment lengths, it is hard for me to see what it is exactly and try to correct it.  Suppose you have an expression `expr=a+b`.  When you type `FullForm[expr]`, this does not *change* `expr` in any way. It simply *reveals* its internal structure. `FullForm` (and other `*Form` functions) are only useful for printing the same expressions in different ways.  If you want to replace `Times` with `Plus`, you still need to operate on `expr` itself, and not ...

Comment: ... `FullForm[expr]`.  When you input something: `Plus[a,b]` and `a+b` are two different ways to write the very same thing. There will be no difference between the data structures that Mathematica constructs from these two textual descriptions.  When Mathematica outputs something, it can also write it in multiple equivalent ways.  `FullForm[expr]`  will print differently than simply `expr`: The `FullForm` wrapped is hidden (but still present!—and this is what makes it "unusable for computation"), and the internal structure is printed explicitly.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thank you, yes, I do/did have a misunderstanding. But now I see that `z/.FullForm-> Evaluate` does lead to what I want.

Comment: What this means in practice: use `FullForm`, `InputForm`, `MatrixForm`, or other similar functions only to *print* the same thing in a different way.  In the vast majority of cases the output from these need not be reused for computation—they just change the way expressions are printed (for readability).

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke you will get into a lot of confusion by using random procedures you have not understood. `/. FullForm -> Evaluate` is as good as `First` while the latter is not confusing. Also, don't strip FullForm, just don't use it.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Yes, `z /. FullForm -> Evaluate` technically works, but in practice it doesn't do more than `First[z]`.  Just use `FullForm` to *look* at things, but don't assign its output to a variable and do not try to re-use it.

Comment: @Kuba: Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `With` you can get a more interactive feel:

```
With[{Times = Plus, Plus = Times, Power = Times}, 
 2 a + 5 b x^3 + c]

(* (2 + a) c (5 + b + 3 x) *)
```

Comment: I think this is safer than replacement. For the sufficiently paranoid, you can wrap the expression in `Hold[]`, make the injections with `With[]`, and `ReleaseHold[]` afterwards.

Comment: @J.M. Good point. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not convinced you're asking for a well defined operation. Consider the ambiguities of $0$'s that can be considered always added to any expression, and $1$'s that are always multiplied to any expression.

- Do you want $5+0 \mapsto 5$ or $0$?
- Do you want $5\times1\times1 \mapsto 5$ or $7$? (Note e.g. $5 x^2 \mapsto 5+2 x$ in your example)
- Should $25 a \mapsto (25 + a)$ or $(5+5+a)$?

A natural attempt that reproduces your above example is something like:

```
    expr=2 a + 5 b x^3 + c;
    expr/. {Times :> Plus, Plus :> Times, Power :> Times}
```

But you should know there are tons of glitches with this type of game, many related to the type of ambiguities mentioned above, how to handle negative numbers, etc.  If you really want to play it, and you chase down all your use cases, you may still want to consider some sort of canonicalization procedure (e.g. ExpandAll) before your operation.